# Spring Batch - ListPartitioner can cause memory consumption

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing, partitioning

In my spring batch , I have a list partitioner that gives list of Range(startIndex,EndIndex). I am passing a sublist of the original list ( list.sublist(range.startIndex, range.endIndex) to the ListItemReader. This would mean that we end up creating sublists = number of partitions.
With large number of partitions and parallel jobs running , will memory be an issue eventually ?

```
I am not happy about enormous sublists getting created. Need help here.
```

```
open class ListPartitioner(private val listSize: Int) : Partitioner {
override fun partition(gridSize: Int): MutableMap<String, ExecutionContext> {
val totalPartitions = getTotalPartitions(gridSize, listSize)
var partitionSize = getPartitionSize(gridSize, listSize)
val partitions: MutableMap<String, ExecutionContext> = HashMap(gridSize)
var index = 0
for (partitionIndex in 0 until totalPartitions) {
  val range = Range(index, index + partitionSize)
  index += partitionSize
  partitionSize = getPartitionSize(gridSize, (listSize - (gridSize * (partitionIndex + 1))))
  val context = ExecutionContext()
  context.put(PARTITION_KEY, range)
  partitions["$PARTITION_PREFIX$partitionIndex"] = context
}
return partitions

} 
private fun getTotalPartitions(gridSize: Int, listSize: Int): Int { return if (listSize / gridSize > 0) (listSize / gridSize) + (listSize % gridSize) else 1 }

private fun getPartitionSize(gridSize: Int, listSize: Int): Int { return if ((listSize / gridSize) > 0) gridSize else (listSize % gridSize) } }

 @Bean 
@Primary 
@Qualifier("listItemReader") 
@StepScope 
fun itemReader( @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['range']}") partition: Range ): ItemReader<SomeClassDTO?>? 
{var listOfItems = servletContext.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME_PROCESSING_INPUT_DATA) as List<SomeClassDTO> 
return ListItemReader(listOfItems.subList(partition.start,partition.end) ) 
} }}
```

The above takes in sublist and eventually a lot of sublists will get created and cost memory.

```
listOfItems.subList(partition.start,partition.end)
```

Comment: I would like to understand if ListItemReader from Springbatch is efficient in managing the sublists that it would receive ( in my case I will end up creating thousands of sublist)